# How to set the dimensions of the document?

Tags: pdf, paper-size

I would like to create with LaTeX a PDF document whose pages have prescribed dimensions. For instance, I would like to create a document whose pages have dimension 5cm x 5cm.

Is it possible, and if yes how would do that?

Comment: look at the `geometry` package. It has _lots_ of options.

Comment: I have looked quickly but, for instance, `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[height=5cm, width=5cm, top=1cm, bottom=1cm, left=1cm, right=1cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
test
\end{document}` won't do it, unfortunately. The size of the page seems to depend more on the `class` used.

Comment: But, this `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=5cm, paperwidth=5cm, top=1cm, bottom=1cm, left=1cm, right=1cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
test
\end{document}` is working perfectly !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is : with the `geometry` package.

For instance,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=5cm, 
            paperwidth=5cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

will make it.

Comment: The margin settings have nothing to do with the goal of getting a certain paper size of the pdf file, so I removed those from your MWE.